# Links continue to point to live server - Drupal Live to localhost

Tags: drupal, testing, localhost, relative-path

I have inherited a Drupal 6 site to maintain.

I am new to Drupal so there is an element of learning as I go.

I have encountered a strange issue after attempting to set up a test site on my local machine.

All my links on my local site continue to point to the live server. So all menus, login buttons, etc. all point towards the live site.

Steps I have taken:

- checked settings.php to ensure that $base_url is set to "http://localhost:456"
- checked settings.php to ensure that MySQL settings are correct
- Taken an SQL dump of the entire local database and searched for any references to live site URL
- deleted all the local cache data from database
- Checked various blocks to ensure that there was no hard coding of links
- Disabled language support as that does use separate URLS for each language

I am at a total loss as to where to go from here.

I can navigate through the site locally by replacing the URL in the address bar to point to the local site, and I have even managed to change the local theme so I can see which version of the site I'm on. The fact that I could do this means that the database is set up correctly.

Totally stumped as to where to go from here. Any takers?

Comment: Cleared the browser cache, deleted database cache.. downloaded a totally new browser(opera) and viewed it in that, same issues as before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that in the 'variable' table there was an entry with the URL for default language pointing to live site. There is a 'language' table which holds the URLS for each language e.g. eng.example.com for english  and ru.example.com for russian. I had changed the urls here to point to local server, but it seems there is also an entry in the variable table which needed to be changed.

In case anybody runs into this problem and wants to change it, you need to change the metadata for the entry as well where S22 represents a string of 22 characters, you need to change it to  the length of the string that you are entering, youll see what I mean when you look in the table!
Also, you need to clear your cache after making any change.

Comment: Helps me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your local server, go to your site directory->site->default and open your settings.php file
look for the base url and comment out that line it should be around line 144

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if you read my question again you will see that is the first thing I mentioned under the 'steps I have taken'.. !

Answer (score 0):

The only thing left is you need to a search for the live site url in your complete code base. See if any module is changing the base url using the code. Though I am not sure how it can be done using code.

However instead of replacing the url you can edit the hosts file and add an entry like

```
127.0.0.1    livesite.com
```

If you are using Linux the location of the file is `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I moved the entire site from the remote to the local server to work on, but whenever I loaded the site it went to the live site. I believe the problem was the .htpaccess file. I updated all the core Drupal files, but as the .htpaccess file was hidden I didn't notice it was still there.

Note that even after I removed it, it wasn't until I opened a different site on the local server and then went back that the path worked correctly.